# Can the CPU scout players for me?

Tags: madden-17

In previous Madden games with in-season scouting, there's been an option to allow the CPU to do it for you.

In Madden 17, I can't find one. If I sim a week, I lose half the unused scouting points from the previous week. I assumed that simming multiple weeks would result in the CPU scouting for me, since it would be impossible for me to spend the points myself, but alas that is not the case. I tried simming about 4 weeks, and lost hundreds of scouting points without getting any additional information. Not sure if they really thought that through.

This is a problem, as I'm trying to set up a franchise where I just sim each regular season. That franchise isn't going to do too well if they never scout any college players.

Is there a way to get the computer to scout players for you? How?

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be, no.

My eventual solution to this was to just let the computer draft as well. If it's drafting, then I don't need to see the scouting reports.

Of course, the computer is terrible at drafting, but it would probably be terrible at scouting as well.

If nothing else, this should help prevent the power creep from my great drafting that eventually leads to me winning 8 out of 10 super bowls and starting a new franchise for some competition.